How to enable Intellisense when using YouTube API with Python in VSCode
I want to get the IntelliSense in VSCode when using Google YouTube API with Python. But I don't know the detailed step.
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
api_key="****"
youtube=build("youtube","v3",developerKey=api_key)
request=youtube.channels().list(
    part="statistics",
    forUsername="****"
)

I can get Intellisense when inputting the "build(...)" method. But I can't get Intellisense when I input "channels()" and "list()" methods. Should I import other modules? When I code in Google Colab, I can get the Intellisense feature for all of the methods above. But in VSCode, only the "build" method has Intellisense.

Hello, is the interpreter you are using that contains the environment where the library is installed? You can choose to use .venv/Scripts/activate to go into the environment and then install the library. Or use PyLint to see what hints are suggested for what. Hover over the channels() method and you can see what the suggestion prompts.

@Jeanneli Yes, I install the google-api-python-client in the virtual environment by venv. And the code ran well. When I hover over the method "channels()" and "list()", it gave a hint "(function) channels/list: Any" though the googlecolab could gave a more precise hints. And VSCode recognized variable "youtube" as Any, while googlecolab could recognize it as Resource as expected.

The package google-api-python-client doesn't provide type hints.
You could install third-party type stubs or add type hints manually by running the following command in your terminal:
pip install google-api-python-client-stubs

Reload your VSCode after installing package. Then Intellisense will work.


You save my life! Never thank you enough!!!
BTW, how could I know one package can provide hints or not?

This only works on some packages. The stubs were generated automatically based on Google's Discovery Documents, that are bundled with google-api-python-client as of v2.
